# can I audit use of http connector in power apps?

Tags: powerapps

is it possible to audit which user used "http connector" in power apps? there are some doubts of the client to enable http connector (that is needed for activation of core flows in PowerApps CoE starter kit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine which Power **Apps** are using a *Custom Connector*:

- In Power Automate, use the [`Get Custom Connectors as Admin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/powerappsforadmins/#get-custom-connectors-as-admin) action OR
- Use the `Get-AdminPowerAppConnector` [PowerShell cmdlet](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/gdpr-admin-powershell-cmdlets/)

Comment: thanks, this is on app level, but can this be determined on user level as well?

Comment: I believe you'll have to query the [O365 audit and security logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/logging-powerapps). Another option is to roll your own. For every app that uses a Custom Connector, add some code to the `OnStart` property to the effect of: `Patch(myTrackingTable, Defaults(myTrackingTable), {user: User().Email})`.